# Mockito GregorianCalendate.getTime() causing error

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I am trying to mock the return of GregorianCalendar.getTime() which should be a Date().
But am getting this error

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.WrongTypeOfReturnValue: 
Date$$EnhancerByMockitoWithCGLIB$$91e3d4b7 cannot be returned by getTimeInMillis()
getTimeInMillis() should return long

Mockito.when(gregorianCalendar.getTime()).thenReturn(date);
```

Both gregorianCalendar and date are mocked objects.

Any advice on how to fix this?
All help much appreciated

Answer (score 7):

Take a look on implementation of `getTime()` that is located in super class of `GregorianCalendar` named `Calendar`:

```
public final Date getTime() {
    return new Date(getTimeInMillis());
}
```

This means that you should probably try to mock `getTimeInMillis()` instead:

`Mockito.when(gregorianCalendar.getTimeInMillis()).thenReturn(date.getTime());`

Answer (score 0):

A `GregorianCalendar` is a value object.  The best advice about mocking value objects is never to do so.  Just create a real `GregorianCalendar` with the date that you want to use.